# Confuse on react-redux and Container/Component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I am new to React Native (and also javascript).

I actually don't quite understand on the function "connect" in react-redux, and its relationship with Container/Component.

I saw the following code in container.js, how it actually affecting component.js?

```
export default connect(state => ({
    state: state.counter
}),
(dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(counterActions, dispatch)
})
)(CounterApp);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You really should check http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html to get hang of the basics :)

Answer (score 0):

The connect function returns a modified version of your component `CounterApp` that has

- been subscribed to changes in the store affecting it.
- is supplied with a state property containing the counter state.
- is supplied with an actions property (presumably) containing the action creators.